# Implementing redux in Angular 7 gives error TS2307: Cannot find module 'redux'. error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux

I am learning Redux and I am trying to implement it in Angular 7 using ng2-redux. I  saw that it was deprecated on the npm page, so I installed it using the suggested `npm install @angular-redux/store'`. I configured my app.module and it gives me this error: `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'redux'.` Am I importing it wrong, what may be causing this? I tried searching over the internet but I didn't find anything. Here is my `app.module` file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgRedux, NgReduxModule } from '@angular-redux/store'
import { rootReducer, AppState } from '../app/store';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { 
  constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<AppState>) {
    ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer,  {});
  }
}
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-redux-playground",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: please check in the `node_module` folder if that contains the `@angular-redux` package in it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to install the package `redux` as well. Run:

```
npm install --save redux
```

See the [quickstart guide](https://github.com/angular-redux/store/blob/master/articles/quickstart.md).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
npm install --save redux @angular-redux/store
```